# BCS StreamAccessor method

Tags: bcs, fast-search

I've implemented a StreamAccessor method for my BCS indexing connector. 
My source is an SQL database which has a table that contains records. 
Some of the records have links to files. My problem is that I’m not sure what to return in my method when there is no file to read. 
If I return null - the results have no content type.
If I return an empty memorystream - the results gets a content type of application-octet stream which isn’t what they really are.

How can I construct my StreamAccessor method so it will know when to read files and when to ignore the record and move on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send in an empty HTML document as answered on your question here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fastsharepoint/thread/bd417568-1404-4e8a-ba42-3f65415f9900/